# Como fazer consulta SQL que ignora maiúsculas, minúsculas e acentos?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho um banco de dados com cadastro de vários filmes, e gostaria de criar uma consulta SQL que ignorasse a presença de letras maiúsculas, minúsculas, acentos e ç. Por exemplo ao buscar por "coracao valente" gostaria que a consulta me retornasse o registro do filme Coração Valente. Porém não sei como fazer, atualmente tenho usado 'like' para retornar registros que encontram a palavra digitada em qualquer posição.

```
select * from filmes where titulo like '%Valente%'
```

Uso como SGBD o PostgreSQL e estou iniciando os estudos com linguagem SQL e modelagem de banco de dados relacionais. Desde já agradeço a colaboração de todos, qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para fazer uma busca independente de maiúsculas ou minúsculas troque o `LIKE` pelo [`ILIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html).

O operador `ILIKE` é específico do PostgreSQL e seu comportamento é semelhante ao `LIKE`. A única diferença é que ele é *case-insensitive*, ou seja, não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas.

Para ignorar acentos instale a extensão, [unaccent](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/unaccent.html) ela está disponível do postgres 9.1 para frente, abra o pgAdmin ou similar e digite

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

A consulta deve ficar assim:

```
SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE unaccent(titulo) ilike unaccent('%Valente%')
```

**Refêrencia**

[Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11005036/1342547)